# DevExpress VerticalGrid Validate event and behavior with RadioButton cell editors

Tags: radio-button, devexpress

I'm using the VerticalGrid in MultiRecordView.  Its Validate event fires when the grid detects that a record that has been changed is losing focus. I'm writing data to the database from this event.

My users want to use the keyboard left/right arrow keys to move forwards and backwards through the recordset, so I trap those keys and set the FocusedRecord accordingly.

If one of the row editors is a RepositoryItemRadioButton, the Validate event doesn't always fire. The users will click on the radio-button value desired and then, before they click on another row in the record, they'll hit the arrow key to move to the next record. The change to the radio button group has not been detected by the grid in that sequence of events.
The radio button change is detected only when the button loses focus.

Is there a way to cause the vertical grid to recognize that a radio button editor has been changed and fire the Validate event, if the user doesn't give another row in the record the focus?

I thought EditValueChangedFiringMode property controlled that behavior, but setting it to Default or to Buffered does not have the desired effect.

Thanks